# Reference key not useable when authenticating to MIFARE Classic card

Tags: authentication, smartcard, mifare, contactless-smartcard, pcsc

I'm trying to authenticate to a MIFARE Classic card using PC/SC based APDU. I'm using a SCL3711 reader and the key A `00 00 00 00 00 03`.

```
>> FF 82 00 60 06 00 00 00 00 00 03
<< 90 00
>> FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 08 60 00
<< 69 84
(Check error : referenced data invalidated)
```

I'm sure the data stored in the corresponding sector trailer is ok, as using a native reader I'm able to read/write the value. Actually this is the way I was able to restore the key once this happened.

When using other keys like `FF FF FF FF FF FF`, or `01 02 03 04 05 06`, or whatever "normal", everything is working as expected.

a)  With valid key FF FF FF FF FF FF

```
>> FF 82 00 60 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF
<< 90 00
>> FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 08 60 00
<< 90 00
```

b) With invalid key 01 02 03 04 05 06

```
>> FF 82 00 60 06 01 02 03 04 05 06
<< 90 00
>> FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 08 60 00
<< 69 82
```

I have gone through the PC/SC specs (Part 3) and haven't found any place where they include any reference to valid or invalid keys. It is the first time I'm not able to use a key.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: did you check if the key was changed at all?

Comment: @MaxMustermann I was not changing the key or sector trailer at all. I was just trying to authenticate. As you can see with the valid key (example a) the authentication is succesful. However using the initial included commands I get the error mentioned (6984), which is not expected.